# Prove rigorously that $4n^2 - 2 \geq 2n$ for $n \geq 1$

Tags: inequality

Apologies that this is a real low-level question, I'm having a bit of a brain-fart as they say.

I would like to show rigorously that $4n^2-2 \geq 2n$ for $n \geq 1$. This is obvious by inspection but for some reason I'm struggling to show it.

Comment: $4n^2-2n-2=2(n-1)(2n+1)\ge 0$ because, for $n\ge 1$ both $n-1\ge 0$ and $2n+1\ge 0$.

Comment: Ah, there it is. Knew I was missing the obvious.

Comment: This is, actually, kind-of, non-obvious until certain level of math education (polynomial factorization needs to be done). Maybe an easier way is to notice that, for $n\ge 1$ you have both $n^2\ge n$ and $n^2\ge 1$ and then add those together ($2n^2\ge n+1$) and multiply by $2$...

Answer (score 2):

$4n^2 - 2n - 2 = (2n + 1)(2n - 2) = 2(n-1)(2n+1) >= 0$ for $n >= 1$

Answer (score 0):

Let $f(x) = 4x^2-2x-2$.

We first observe that $f(1)=0$ and $f(2)>0$. Then the derivative of $f$ is $f'(x) = 8x - 2 > 0$ for all $x \geq 1$. So $f$ is increasing function. Since $f(2)>0$ , $$f(x) \geq 0$$ for all $x \geq 1$

**Edit:**

Here is a method which does not make use of derivatives.
We know that for any positive $a$ and $b$ by AM - GM inequality, $$a+b >2\sqrt(ab)$$

Take $a=2n^2$ and $b= 2n^2-2$, which would imply that $4n^2-2 \geq 4n\sqrt{n^2-1} \geq 2n$ for all $n\geq 1$.